# GET request to REST API

Tags: javascript, rest, api, get

`http://www.serveraddress.com/api/users/1` is valid and the value is in proper JSON format.

The JSON:

```
{
   "id":1,
   "name":"Ryan Chenkie",
   "email":"ryanchenkie@gmail.com",
   "battles_won":0,
   "created_at":"2017-02-25 19:20:58",
   "updated_at":"2017-02-25 19:20:58",
   "blobs":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "name":"Blob 1",
         "type":"type A",
         "color":"red",
         "alive":1,
         "level":1,
         "exercise_level":-302,
         "cleanliness_level":-302,
         "health_level":-302,
         "owner_id":1,
         "created_at":"2017-02-25 19:20:58",
         "updated_at":"2017-02-26 01:23:05"
      },
      {
         "id":5,
         "name":"Blob 5",
         "type":"type C",
         "color":"blue",
         "alive":1,
         "level":1,
         "exercise_level":-302,
         "cleanliness_level":-302,
         "health_level":-302,
         "owner_id":1,
         "created_at":"2017-02-25 19:20:58",
         "updated_at":"2017-02-26 01:23:05"
      }
   ]
}
```

When I try to run getUser(), I get a `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`.

What's wrong with my code? Is my `setRequestHeader` incorrect?

```
getUser(1);

function getUser(userId) {
    var usersUrl = "http://www.serveraddress.com/api/users/";
    var params = userId;
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xhttp.open("GET", usersUrl + params, true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send();
    var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);

    return response;
```

}

Comment: What is the resulting JSON? I guess there is an error there.

Comment: @Psi I edited the OP to include the JSON. I checked with a JSON formatter which said it was valid JSON.

Comment: Check the response in your browser tools or Fiddler. Make sure it's actually getting that JSON as a response.

Comment: @falafel How are you sending the JSON from the server. Can you include that part of code?

Answer (score 1):

Because the xmlhttprequest is asynchronous, the function is returning `response` (which is empty) before the request is even sent.
To get the responseText after the request completes, use a callback function that is called when the event's `load` event fires:

```js
function getUser(userId, callback) {
    var usersUrl = "http://www.serveraddress.com/api/users/";
    var params = userId;
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    
    xhttp.addEventListener('load', callback);
    xhttp.addEventListener('error', () => console.log("Request to "+usersUrl+params+" failed"));
    
    xhttp.open("GET", usersUrl + params, true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send();
}
getUser(1, function() {
    console.log(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
});
```